# How to resolve Loop carried dependency preventing loop vectorization while using -fast in PGI compiler in OpenACC

Tags: c, for-loop, openacc, pgi

I want to parallelize a particle method based fluid flow code using OpenACC in C language. I am quite new to OpenACC and trying to understand its basics while currently applying it to the code on a multicore computer. Later, I shall try to offload it to GPU. I have added some #pragmas to the for loops in the code. In a portion of code, when I compile the code without -fast, it compiles without any problems but parallelizes only the outer loop, however, when I include -fast during compiling the code, it gives me some data dependency messages and inner loop(s) are not parallelized. I have tried many things after reading the available literature including use of restrict with declaration of pointers and use of atomic and routine statements etc but so far nothing has seemed to work. The abridged version of the part of the code is here:

```
// the code intends to compute the total number of neighbour particles of "iParticle" in 
// particle.numberOfNeighborParticles[iParticle] and saves the list of these neighbour particles in
// particle.neighborTable[iParticle][Neigh]

int iX, iY;
#pragma acc parallel loop private(iX, iY)                                       //line 98
for (iParticle = 0; iParticle < particle.totalNumber; iParticle++)
{
    BUCKET_findBucketWhereParticleIsStored(&iX, &iY, iParticle, position);

#pragma acc loop seq                                                           // line 133
    for (jX = iX - 1; jX <= iX + 1; jX++)
    {
       .....
#pragma acc loop seq                                                           // line 179
        for (jY = iY - 1; jY <= iY + 1; jY++)
        {
     ......
#pragma acc loop                                                              // line 186
            for (iStoredParticle = 0; iStoredParticle < domain.bucket[jX][jY].count; iStoredParticle++)
            {
                jParticle = domain.bucket[jX][jY].list[iStoredParticle];

                xij = (position[XDIM][jParticle] - position[XDIM][iParticle]);

                distanceIJ_squared = xij * xij;

                yij = (position[YDIM][jParticle] - position[YDIM][iParticle]);
                distanceIJ_squared += yij * yij;
                if (distanceIJ_squared > parameter.maxRadius_squared)
                    continue;

                NEIGH_addParticleInNeighborTable(iParticle, jParticle, particle.numberOfNeighborParticles, particle.neighborTable);
            }
        }
    }
}

//The *NEIGH_addParticleInNeighborTable()* function is as under:

void
NEIGH_addParticleInNeighborTable( 
                                 int iParticle
                                 ,int jParticle
                                 ,int *restrict numberOfNeighborParticles
                                 ,int **restrict neighborTable
                                 ){

  int iNeigh;
    iNeigh = numberOfNeighborParticles[iParticle];
    neighborTable[iParticle][iNeigh] = jParticle;
    #pragma acc atomic
    numberOfNeighborParticles[iParticle]++; 
}
```

EDIT:

I have added a pseudo code below, which is quite similar to my problem, to elaborate the issue:

```
//This pseudo code intends to find the contiguous states from a given list for each state of US
count=0;
//state[] is a list of all the states of US
#pragma acc paralel loop gang
for(i=0;i<no_of_states_in_US;i++)
{
    iState=state[i];
    #pragma acc loop vector
    for (j = 0; j < no_of_states_to_check_from_for[iState]; j++){    //no_of_states_to_check_from_for[iState] may be 5
        jState = names_of_states_to_check_for_iState[j];   // for KS the given states to check from may be CO, NE, CA, UT and OK
    // some logic to check whether jState is contiguous to iState
        if(jState is_NOT_adjacent_to_iState) continue;
        //race condition occurs below if inner loop is vectorized, but no race condition if outer loop is parallelized only
        // Any suggestions / work around to vectorize the inner loop here and to avoid race condition would be helpful
        contiguous_state[iState][count]=jState;  
    #pragma acc atomic //?? does not seem to work   
count++;
    }
}
```

I am interested to vectorize the inner loop becuase this portion of code is among the computational intensive parts and is repeated several times in the code.
I am using PGI 19.4 community edition on Windows 10. Help in this regard is requested. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second, edited question, so long as the order in which count is updated doesn't matter, then you can use an atomic capture instead.  This will capture count's value into a local variable so you don't need to worry about it changing.  Something like:

```
int cnt;
#pragma acc atomic capture 
{
    cnt = count; 
    count++;
}
contiguous_state[iState][cnt]=jState;
```

If the order of count does matter, then the loop is not parallelizable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not an OpenACC issue, rather the compiler is just telling you that it's unable to vectorize the loops (vectorization is enabled with -fast or -O2) due to potential loop dependencies on particle.numberOfNeighborParticles and particle.neighborTable. This shouldn't effect your results nor the OpenACC parallelization of the loop, you'll just not get the added performance benefit of vectorization.

You can try adding the flag "-Msafeptr" where you're asserting to the compiler that there's no pointer aliasing, which typically causes these types of issues.  The caveat being if you do have aliasing, the code is likely to get incorrect results.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable insight and suggestions. It appears that there is a race condition in NEIGH_addParticleInNeighborTable() function which creates problems in vectorization of the inner loop. The initial value of _numberOfNeighborParticles[iParticle]_ would be zero for all the "vector threads" giving rise to the race condition. Is there any function in OpenACC to get the numerical ID of "vector threads" for the inner loop that may be used to initialize _iNeigh_ variable instead?

Comment: The OpenACC standard does not have "thread id" mostly because the enumeration depends on the target device.  We (PGI) provide an extension "__pgi_vectoridx" to get the vector id, but given we ignore "vector" and only use "gang" when targeting Multicore, it's not going to be of much use here.  Also, it returns the vector id within a gang, not an enumerated global vector id.  To get this, you'd need to use "id =  (__pgi_gangidx()*num_gangs)+__pgi_vectoridx();"  "num_gangs" would be a user variable which is also used to fix the number of gangs via the "num_gangs" clause.  I'd avoid using it here.

Comment: While I don't know you're code, from what you describe, doesn't this race condition prevent parallelization of the outer loop?

Comment: @ Mat Colgrove I am sorry that the code I added previously, was quite complex. Now I have edited the question and added a pseudocode (sort of) to elaborate the issue. Hopefully, it will serve to clarify that there is no race condition in the outer loop and explain the issue at hand. Your kind suggestions / comments to address the issue are requested. Thanks